# Como agrupar varias columnas y contar los registros con LINQ desde un archivo CSV en C#

Tags: c#, linq, csv

Tengo un problema al agrupar varias columnas y contar su registos en cada columna leyendolo desde un archivo CSV, Ejemplo CSV registros:

```
Nombre,Apellido,FechaDeRegistro,Aceptado
David,tod,09/09/2014,SI
David,lopez,09/09/2011,NO
David,cortez,09/09/2011,SI
Maurice,perez,09/09/2012,SI
Maurice,ruiz,09/09/2013,NO
```

El usuario en un formulario seleccionara  un periodo de fechas ej. 01/01/2010 y 31/12/2015 el programa debe arrojar en un DataGridView, cuantas personas con el nombre de David y Mauricio fueron aceptadas a la universidad y cuantas no lo fueron dentro de ese periodo. Y Lo debe mostrar asi:

```
Nombre,TotaldePersonas,Aceptadas,NoAceptadas
David,3,2,1
Maurice,2,1,1
```

Tengo el codigo para contar el total de personas que se encontraron en ese periodo, pero no se como hacerlo para multiples columnas y contarlo.

```
 DataTable dtDataSource = new DataTable();

csvfile = localitation;
            fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(csvfile);

                dtDataSource.Columns.Add(Nombre);
                dtDataSource.Columns.Add("Total");

                var people = fileContent
                    .Skip(1)
                    .Select(line =>
                    {
                        var parts = line.Split(',');

                        return new Person
                        {

                            Nombre = parts[0],
                            Apellido = parts[1],
                            FechaRegistro = DateTime.ParseExact(parts[2], "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                        };
                    });



                var groups = people
                .Where(p => p.FechaRegistro >= DateTime.ParseExact(DateIn.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) && p.FechaRegistro <= DateTime.ParseExact(DateFin.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
               .GroupBy(p => p.Nombre)
               .Select(firstNameGroup => new
               {
                   Name = firstNameGroup.Key,
                   Count = firstNameGroup.Count(),

               });


                foreach (var group in groups)
                {

                    dtDataSource.Rows.Add(group.Name, group.Count);

                }

if (dtDataSource != null)
                {

                    dataGridViewReporte.DataSource = dtDataSource;

                }
```

Con una clase llamada `Person`

```
class Person
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaRegistro { get; set; }
 // public string Aceptado { get; set; }
}
```

Desconozco como hacerlo con esta logica o si hay otra mas facil de implementar para mi seria de mucha ayuda, gracias! OJO Este codigo fue adaptado en forma de que se entendiera.. y lo encontre en la comunidad en ingles, si hay una mejor solucion y mas simple, se los agradeceria mucho.

Comment: una pregunta.. sabes usar linq y consultas a bases?? o es solo una prueba??? parece una solucion ultra compleja para lo que estas tratando de hacer. no creo que el archivo csv tenga millones de registros, y esto suena obviamente a tarea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asi es como lo haría yo. Primero,en la clase Person el campo aceptado lo convertiria en bool, quedando asi:

```
class Person
{
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaRegistro { get; set; }
    public bool Aceptado { get; set; }
}
```

Despues, a la hora de pasar el csv a una `List<Person>`, sería asi:

```
var people = fileContent
            .Skip(1)
            .Select(line =>
            {
                var parts = line.Split(',');

                return new Person
                {

                    Nombre = parts[0],
                    Apellido = parts[1],
                    FechaRegistro = DateTime.ParseExact(parts[2], "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    Aceptado=parts[3]=="SI"?true : false
                };
            });
```

Por último, aqui se genera el listado que necesitabas:

```
DateTime dtIni = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2010");
DateTime dtFin = DateTime.Parse("31/12/2015");

var lista = people.Where(x => (x.FechaRegistro > dtIni && x.FechaRegistro < dtFin))
                            .GroupBy(x=>x.Nombre)
                            .Select(firstNameGroup=>new
                            {
                                Name = firstNameGroup.Key,
                                Count = firstNameGroup.Count(),
                                Aceptados = firstNameGroup.Count(x=>x.Aceptado),
                                NoAceptados = firstNameGroup.Count(x => !x.Aceptado)

                            });
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @Pikoh me disculpo ante mi actitud si ofendi a alguien, pero conteste lo que me preguntaron y si se malinterpreto ofrezco una disculpa.

Comment: No te preocupes @DavidTod. Todos podemos equivocarnos y el texto escrito puede malinterpretarse a veces. Por mi parte por supuesto acepto las disculpas y me alegro si mi respuesta te fue de ayuda. Un saludo

Comment: Asi es pues ya ni modo ya paso, y me ayudo mucho te lo agradezco, se adecuo perfectamente a mi aplicacion, muchas gracias saludos!